# Why is "al que" used in the sentence 'Colocarán un reloj, *al que* deberá dar cuerda'?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

I've been reading through the book "La mecánica del corazón" and I am confused about the use of *al que* in this sentence:

> Para salvarlo, le colocarán un reloj de madera, **al que** deberá dar cuerda durante toda su vida y le causará un sinfín de molestias.

Could someone please explain why the preposition 'a' is in this sentence?

Comment: Hi Sionnach, welcome to Spanish.SE!  To help us give you a better answer, why do you think the *a* is unneeded?  Also, could you provide a bit more context of the sentence?  Maybe the sentence before/after as well?  When a sentence has a lot of object pronouns it is easier to help out if we know what each one actually is.

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks for the quick response!  it's not that I think it's unneeded, I'm just trying to understand why it's there.  I have read quite a few articles on prepositions and I can't tie it together with what I see in that sentence so I'm just trying to learn more about it.  The sentence before the one I posted is "Allí nacerá Jack, hijo de una prostituta, y cuyo corazón está dañando".  And the sentence after is "claro que para mantener su corazón deberá atenerse a una serie de reglas.

Comment: @Sionnach I believe it’s because in this instance ‘dar’ is functioning as a verb of transference, therefore requiring the ‘a’.

Comment: @Traveller - I'm not familiar with that terminology, "verb of transference."  Are you saying that the verb is transitive?

Comment: @aparente No, I’m saying that ‘dar’ and a few other verbs sometimes convey the idea of transferring something. So in the example in the OP’s question, although ‘dar cuerda’ is the verb the ‘a’ is needed to complete it. My Argentinian spanish teacher used the phrase ‘verbos de transferencia’ when he explained this to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in the definition and usage of the expression *dar cuerda*.  As defined in the [DRAE](http://chttps://dle.rae.es/?id=BaTeKSV),

> dar cuerda a un mecanismo
>
> 1. loc. verb. Tensar la cuerda o resorte que lo pone en marcha y le permite funcionar.

In English we say *wind [up] a clock, wind a watch* (where "up" is optional), but in Spanish it's different, we say *dar cuerda **al** reloj*.

There are other expressions that follow this pattern, for example

> dar fin a: *to end*

Compare the sentence you were having trouble with to

> deberá dar cuerda al reloj de madera durante toda su vida

I think that once you understand how this expression, *dar cuerda a* works, the sentence you asked about will make more sense.

Here is a crude literal translation of the sequence of words, that may help you see what's going on:

> le colocarán un reloj de madera, al que deberá dar cuerda | *they will insert/install a wooden heart, to which he will need to provide spring action*

Comment: Just to make sure I'm on the right path to understanding this.  Is the 'a' in dar cuera a used because we're introducing an indirect object? In the case of dar cuerda al reloj we are providing spring action to a clock.   If that is the case then in my original question is 'al que' used because it's referring to an indirect object (the clock)

Comment: @Sionnach - Yes. "Cuerda" is the direct object of "dar," and "el reloj" is the indirect object of "dar." Note it is possible to write a sentence using "dar cuerda" that doesn't have an indirect object, for example, "Un reloj automático es un reloj que se va dando cuerda «automáticamente»." (https://www.chrono24.es/magazine/que-es-un-reloj-automatico-y-como-funciona-p_40195/)

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  I'm understanding this much better now.

Answer (score 1):

"Al" is the contraction of "a el". "A" is a preposition that, [among other uses](https://dle.rae.es/?id=002rZ9U%7C003Ov93) (the meaning of prepositions can depend on the context) can introduce an object (both direct and indirect). Thus, it might depend on the context, but the Spanish preposition "a" can usually be translated with the English preposition "to"

> To save him, they will put a wooden heart, **to** which he will need to wind up for all his life and which will cause him endless pain.

Basically it is saying

> Deberá dar cuerda **a** el corazón  de madera / He will need to wind up de wooden heart

so the preposition introduces a DC.

Other examples ([from this site](https://comoescribirbien.com/uso-de-las-preposiciones/)):

> ¿Ves **a** Luis? (complemento directo).
>
> Se lo robé **a** Miguel (complemento indirecto).

[These rules](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=ctMgM8Bp2D6ELPuNfg) might help to explain when you need the "a" pronoun and when is not needed (or wrongly used) before a OD.

Comment: Thanks Diego.  That answer was super helpful.  I just have one minor question.  "Deberá dar cuerda a el corazón de madera / He will need to wind up de wooden heart" - in this case is the wooden heart not the direct object since it receives the action of winding? I could still be misunderstanding this though.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the confusion. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Sionnach No, with the verb *dar* the direct object is the thing given (in this case *cuerda*) and the indirect object is the receiver (in this case *el corazón de madera*). The linked RAE article states that *a* never precedes an inanimate object acting as direct object (1.3 a)

Comment: This doesn't work as an answer because you've misunderstood how the expression is used in English. It should be: "To save him, they install a wooden heart, t̶o̶  which he will need to wind up." (Note the strike-out of "to".)

Comment: @aparente001 Why do you think that detail of the "to which" makes this answer completely wrong/useless? I think that the key of this question is what is the preposition introducing, something I tried to explain in my answer.  Also, in your own answer you write an identical example "they will insert/install a wooden heart, **to** which he will need to provide spring action". How does this reconcile with the comment you made to my answer? Why the same  "to which" makes my answer completely invalid and not to work but you then provide the same example as valid for your own answer? Please explain.

Comment: In my "crude literal translation," I purposely looked for a parallel formulation that would contain the preposition.  I find that sometimes it's helpful to provide this sort of parallel formulation for learners to help them understand the function of each word in a Spanish sentence.  (I think it's okay to do that IF one makes clear how artificial it is.) Note, "provide spring action to a watch" is sort of okay -- I mean, I can get away with it for explanation purposes -- but "wind to a watch" doesn't work on any level. "To wind a watch" and "dar cuerda **a** un reloj" really aren't parallel...

Comment: ... constructions.  I think it's illuminating that @guifa asked OP, "why do you think the **a** is unneeded?"  Spanish speakers are so used to using this construction, "dar cuerda a un reloj," that it is often not immediately clear how different it is from the English version, "to wind a watch."  Often, as bilinguals, we sort these things out on a subconscious level, and just use the two languages properly, without dissecting everything.

Comment: Your comments don't clarify what I asked about. My answer focus on the preposition introducing a direct/indirect object and tangentially provides the translation for reference / illustration. You say that my example "they install a wooden heart, t̶o̶ which he will need to..." makes my answer to be wrong and completely miss the point, but you use "they will insert/install a wooden heart, *to* which he will need to" for your own answer (identical examples). I'm trying to understand your claim that the [..., **to** which ...] is an invalid example for my answer since you later used it for yours.

Comment: @aparente001 I agree with Diego: while the _to_ part of _to which_ seems to be wrong, I don't think it is quite courteous to debunk the whole answer because of it. What about just focusing on the specific point, by even editing the answer to make it correct? Me, and I am sure Diego, are always grateful to be corrected on our English.

Comment: @Diego and ....

Comment: @fedorqui - Let's take the *which*es out of Diego's sentence: *They will put in a wooden heart; he will need to wind up the heart for his whole life; the wooden heart will cause him endless pain.*  Notice that it's not *he will need to wind up **to** the heart.*  I hope this makes it clearer.